# How to automate wordpress plugin activate and deactivate by php logic?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, activation, deactivation

Is it possible to build logic to control the activation and deactivation 
of specific wordpress plugins , for example Activation/Deactivation triggered by time period?

thanks for knowledge sharing.

Comment: I removed the plugin recommendation part from your question since its off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**

You can use [`activate_plugin()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/activate_plugin) and [`deactivate_plugins()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/deactivate_plugins) to activate/deactivate plugins programmatically.

If you want to control the time at which those actions happen, then you can use [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) too.

**Method 2**

I know you asked about PHP, but if you have WP-CLI installed on your server, you can also write a script that uses [`wp plugin activate`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/plugin/activate/) and [`wp plugin deactivate`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/plugin/deactivate/). Finally, add a cron job to run your script.